# UIPageViewController overscroll is occurring

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I'm using UIPageViewController to house several different UiViewControllers (6 total).

When on the first or last Page of the Controller, I can scroll the Page partially out of view.  Is there a way to prevent this?  I want scrolling for the interim pages, but don't want the first or last page to move of the screen at all since there's nothing before or after them.

Any ideas here?  I assume it should be a simple setting, but can't find it in the docs.  Thanks!!!